# Facebook Page Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm new with phpsdk v4, and I'm trying to get access token for my pages.
I tried with this:

```
<?
include getenv('social');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException; 
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
$access_token =  $_SESSION['facebooklogged'];
$session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
```

And after:

```
$page_access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/320330478029510?fields=access_token', array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
print_r($page_access_token);
```

And:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts?fields=name,access_token,perms');
$pageList = $request->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
print_r($pageList);
```

Both return or id of page, or a empty array();
    Array ( [id] => 320330478029510 ) 
    Array ( )

I created $session from login page, with

```
$logare = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://mysite/facebook/login.php');

try{$session = $logare->getSessionFromRedirect();}catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {$session = null;}
if($session)$_SESSION['facebooklogged'] = $session->getToken();
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Does your user access token include `manage_pages` permission?

Comment: Yes, i request this perm, and i accepted... ($login = $logare->getLoginUrl(array( 'email', 'user_friends' , 'manage_pages')); )

Answer (score 0):

I tried with another account, another admin of page, and work with that...but with my account, still nothing ... I will delete this app from used apps, and i will try again.